# AngularJS: How to passing data from modal to input text

Tags: html, angularjs, input, modal-dialog, dropdown

I have a modal which contains 4 selects (dropdown lists) and I want to get the value of that data from the modal and display them in 4 text inputs in my html.

I do not know how.

this is my modal "filtros.html"

```
<div><div class="modal-header">
<h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Más filtros</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cliente" >Cliente:</label>
    <select id="cliente" class="form-control input-sm" >
        <option value="0"></option> 
        <option ng-repeat="cliente in listaFiltros.clientes" value="{{ cliente }}">{{ cliente }}</option>   
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="producto">Producto:</label>
    <select id="producto" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="0"></option> 
        <option ng-repeat="producto in listaFiltros.productos" value="{{ producto }}">{{ producto }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="origen">Origen:</label>
    <select id="origen" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="0"></option> 
        <option ng-repeat="origen in listaFiltros.origenes" value="{{ origen }}">{{ origen }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="destino">Destino:</label>
    <select id="destino" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="0"></option> 
        <option ng-repeat="destino in listaFiltros.destinos" value="{{ destino }}">{{ destino }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="vm.aceptar()">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Aplicar filtros
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="vm.cancelar()">
    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Cancelar
</button>
```

This is my modal controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
.module('app.modales')
.controller('ControladorModales', ControladorModales);

ControladorModales.$inject = ['$scope', 'servicioTablasDinamicas','$uibModalInstance'];

function ControladorModales($scope, servicioTablasDinamicas, $uibModalInstance){
    var vm = this;

    vm.aceptar  = aceptar;
    vm.cancelar = cancelar;

    $scope.listaFiltros = {
        clientes: [],
        productos: [],
        origenes: [],
        destinos: []
    };

    servicioTablasDinamicas.cargarClientes()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.listaFiltros.clientes = data;
    });
    servicioTablasDinamicas.cargarProductos()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.listaFiltros.productos = data;
    });
    servicioTablasDinamicas.cargarOrigen()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.listaFiltros.origenes = data;
    });
    servicioTablasDinamicas.cargarDestino()
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.listaFiltros.destinos = data;
    });

    function aceptar(){
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function cancelar(){
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
}
})();
```

This is my normal controller code:

```
function cargarDatosFiltrados(){
        $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : 'app/modales/filtros.html',
            controller  : 'ControladorModales',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            backdrop    : 'static'
        }).result.then(function(data){
            vm.guardando = true;
        });
    }
```

some example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Dan, you need to tell us a bit more about how you are implementing the modal

Comment: Hi, i updated my post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following issues with your code.

1. I don't see any `ng-model` attribute on any of your select fields.Look at this example of [how to use select in angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)
2. `aceptar()` method is not returning any values back to the parent controller. You're just closing the modal window. You have to return something like this `$uibModalInstance.close($scope.result);` which has the 4 selected values.